# extract all "ul a" entities from html page that have a certain String in the "title"

Tags: html, regex, parsing, jsoup, wikipedia

In the style of the example on [this page](http://try.jsoup.org/~84yabFwFgJK4VojAbVK3TG-L2oA) I'm trying to get all of the senses in which a particular name could be applied to a specific person based on the wikipedia disambiguation page.

The trouble is that wikipedia pages are highly non-uniform.

One common feature though is that the list of names will appear in a `ul` element as part of a link `a` and in the `title=` component of the link there will be a reference to the name we're looking for. Since these are links to the associated wikipedia pages.

Using jsoup, or some other method, how could I recognize these components?

`h2:contains(people) + ul a`

^that works for when they're all in a section entitled `People` but as I mentioned, this is not always the case.

Perhaps in pseudocode we could do something like this:

`ul a && title contains *String*`

Maybe something like this:

```
a[href], [title]
```

but only matching part of the title, not the whole thing.

---

[This](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Corzine) is an example of a very non-structured page where such a method would be called for.

[This](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Caplan) is an example of one where it's not important.

But I'm trying to make something generalizable that will apply equally well to both types.

Answer (score 0):

This kind of works:

```
        Elements linx = docx.select("a:contains(Corzine)");

        for (Element linq : linx) 
        {
            System.out.println(linq.text());
        }
```

but maybe one among you might hit upon a better solution.